# DailyMed RESTful API

Tags: api, medical

I am trying to access the INDICATIONS, CONTRAINDICATIONS, ADVERSE REACTIONS, and WARNINGS field using the dailymed API. http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/

However, I cannot seem to find information on their web services page on how to do this. https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/app-support-web-services.cfm

I see there are ways to access NDC's, drug names, classes etc, but what I need is the actual monograph-type information that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `/spls/{SETID}` endpoint documented at https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/webservices-help/v2/spls_setid_api.cfm

For example: http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/spls/1efe378e-fee1-4ae9-8ea5-0fe2265fe2d8.xml

Note, this is not super easy to parse. Welcome to SPL!

If you are looking for something simple and clean, check out my previous answer at ' [Query medicine descriptions API](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/query-medicine-descriptions-api/4405#4405) ' and take a look at suggestion #1 which is MedlinePlus (also from HHS/NIH/NLM).

Comment: Can anyone help me with parsing this xml in php ...
xml : https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/spls/7d7495c0-f254-4cf5-acbb-a1fe476977ef.xml

I am unable to replace the referenced Image urls in place ....

Answer (score 3):

Skram is correct, you'll need to use [the API](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/webservices-help/v2/spls_setid_api.cfm) for the full XML of the SPL.

Then you can use the [FDA's Structured Product Labeling Section Headings (LOINC)](http://www.fda.gov/ForIndustry/DataStandards/StructuredProductLabeling/ucm162057.htm) to get the LOINC code referring to the sections you are looking for.

For example, you'd probably want:
**34067-9** INDICATIONS & USAGE SECTION 
**34070-3** CONTRAINDICATIONS SECTION 
**34084-4** ADVERSE REACTIONS SECTION 
**34066-1** BOXED WARNING SECTION 
**54433-8** USER SAFETY WARNINGS SECTION 
**43685-7** WARNINGS AND PRECAUTIONS SECTION 
**34071-1** WARNINGS SECTION

You can find these sections by checking for the above codes in the "code" attribute of "code" nodes. For example:

```
 <code code="34067-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="INDICATIONS &amp; USAGE SECTION"/>
```

Be careful, sometimes there are nested sections.

Answer (score 0):

This to OpenFDA (beta) call may also be helpful.  Text sections are from the labeling, with text labels instead on LOINC codes.  Smaller return to parse.

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=set_id:f7deaf21-a14a-4f9d-a576-ece333219482