# Is there an API for drug approval packages from the FDA?

Tags: openfda, medical

I am building an application where we'd like to reuse information from drug approval packages ([Example](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/nda/2006/021928_s000_ChantixTOC.cfm)).

The [FDA API](https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/) does not have a query interface for drug approval packages. Is there an alternative API for this information, via the FDA or otherwise?

I'd prefer to use an API, rather than writing a scraper for the same.

Comment: What part of the drug approval package are you looking to use? Are you looking to just know if the drug and/or label was approved/processed? I do not believe FDA has an API for this but DailyMed's labelling APIs may have the information you are looking for (see http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/dailymed-restful-api)

Comment: I'm looking to extract several chunks of text via OCR from the various associated documents.

Comment: I mean what fields. Sounds like the answer is not at this time though :(. You might have luck with a bulk FOIA request. Consider using muckrock.com to ease the pain