# Is there an API to get label info on veterinary drugs for farm animals?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

Hopefully it would include species, manufacturer, withdrawal and whether for treatment, control, prevention or growth promotant/feed efficiency - although that info would usually be on the label.

Answer (score 1):

DailyMed.nlm.nih.gov includes veterinary drugs and the full SPLs available via web and XML API.

For example: http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/drugInfo.cfm?setid=96f180f3-2164-4fce-a056-cd5d6b812ab8

See related questions:

- [DailyMed RESTful API](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/dailymed-restful-api)
- [Query medicine descriptions API](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/query-medicine-descriptions-api/4405#4405)